# Wildcard search in python string and then updating the string

Tags: python, string

I have a column named as city. I want to bring the city names to one format ex.

Column sample data :

```
City
Sydney
Sydney-EZ
Bangalore
Bengalore SEZ
Delhi
New Delhi
```

Sydney and Sydney-EZ or any other row containing word Sydney should be replaced by Sydney. Bangalore and Bangalore SEZ ( or any other row containing word Bangalore )  should be replaced by Bangalore . Delhi and New Delhi ( or any other row containing word Delhi ) should be replaced by Delhi.

Comment: Is this a CSV file?

Comment: Yes it is , but i have put in dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply` with lambda

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"City": ["Sydney", "Sydney-EZ", "Bangalore", "Bengalore SEZ"]})
toUpdate = "Sydney"
df["City"] = df["City"].apply(lambda x:toUpdate if toUpdate in x else x )
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
            City
0         Sydney
1         Sydney
2      Bangalore
3  Bengalore SEZ
```